# Android Data Binding cannot id inside <merge> for zxing-android-embedded

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

Dependency reference: [journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)

Description of the problem:
I'm new to Android Data binding & cannot bind the resource id **zxing_viewfinder_view** which is inside `<merge> </merge>`

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my code for understanding.

activity_scan_qr.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_header"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView
            android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_scanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:zxing_scanner_layout="@layout/view_custom_qr_scanner"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

view_custom_qr_scanner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView
    android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_surface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:zxing_framing_rect_height="250dp"
    app:zxing_framing_rect_width="250dp" />

<com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ViewfinderView
    android:id="@+id/zxing_viewfinder_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:zxing_possible_result_points="@color/zxing_custom_possible_result_points"
    app:zxing_result_view="@color/zxing_custom_result_view"
    app:zxing_viewfinder_laser="@color/zxing_custom_viewfinder_laser"
    app:zxing_viewfinder_laser_visibility="true"
    app:zxing_viewfinder_mask="@color/zxing_custom_viewfinder_mask" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/zxing_status_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
    android:text="Place a QR code inside the scan area."
    android:textColor="@color/zxing_status_text" />

</merge>
```

ScanQRActivity.java

```
public class ScanQRActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DecoratedBarcodeView.TorchListener {
    public static final String TAG = ScanQRActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Context mContext;
    Activity mActivity;
    ActivityScanQrBinding binding;

    ActionBar actionBar;

    private CaptureManager capture;
    boolean bFlashLight = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityScanQrBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        mContext = this;
        mActivity = this;

        capture = new CaptureManager(this, binding.zxingBarcodeScanner);
        capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
        capture.setShowMissingCameraPermissionDialog(true);
        capture.decode();

        changeLaserVisibility(true);
    }

    public void changeLaserVisibility(boolean visible) {
        binding.zxingViewfinderView.setLaserVisibility(visible);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> To use data binding you need to place your layout inside  tag.

**Your activity.xml**

```
<layout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ll_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_header"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.DecoratedBarcodeView
            android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_scanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:zxing_scanner_layout="@layout/view_custom_qr_scanner"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

**Your view_custom_qr_scanner.xml file should be**

```
<layout>
           <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
            
            <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView
                android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_surface"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:zxing_framing_rect_height="250dp"
                app:zxing_framing_rect_width="250dp" />
            
            <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.ViewfinderView
                android:id="@+id/zxing_viewfinder_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:zxing_possible_result_points="@color/zxing_custom_possible_result_points"
                app:zxing_result_view="@color/zxing_custom_result_view"
                app:zxing_viewfinder_laser="@color/zxing_custom_viewfinder_laser"
                app:zxing_viewfinder_laser_visibility="true"
                app:zxing_viewfinder_mask="@color/zxing_custom_viewfinder_mask" />
            
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/zxing_status_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
                android:text="Place a QR code inside the scan area."
                android:textColor="@color/zxing_status_text" />
            
            </merge>
    </layout>
```

Comment: I tried but it's still same. 

is my binding is correct? 
`binding.zxingViewfinderView.setLaserVisibility(visible);`

Comment: let me check from my side. Did you rebuild project after change?

Comment: Can you please check again after clean and rebuild your project? It should work

Comment: Still same. cannot bind.

Comment: add layout tag for activity xml also

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, create a new variable of type 'binding' that would be

> private ViewCustomQrScannerBinding bindingCustomScanner

, now in your "OnCreate" under `"binding = ActivityScanQrBinding.inflate (getLayoutInflater ());"`
add this line

> bindingCustomScanner = ViewCustomQrScannerBinding.bind (binding.root)

now when you call the properties of the new view, you call the new 'bindingCustomScanner'

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer...may be a code snippet will help a lot